# React.isValidElement(obj) determines obj to be React.ReactElement<{}> type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have following piece of code

```
// type def
interface Props: { children: React.ReactNode }

React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {

  // uh-oh!
  if (React.isValidElement(child)  && child.props.children) {
    // do sth
  }
}
```

Which causes typescript error:

> semantic error TS2339 Property 'children' does not exist on type '{}'

type of `child` befor exectution `React.isValidElement` is `React.ReactNode`defined as:

```
type React.ReactNode = 
  | string 
  | number 
  | boolean 
  | {} 
  | React.ReactElement<any> 
  | React.ReactNodeArray 
  | React.ReactPortal 
  | null 
  | undefined
```

but after execution of `React.isValidElement` type script determines child to be `React.ReactElement<{}>` - it expects element to have empty `props` which causes an error since it assumes that there is no prop `children` in the element. Code does not compile.

Am I missing something? is there a way to fix that?

my `tsconfig`:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
}
```

typescript: 3.2.0
@types/react": ^16.3.13"
@types/react-dom": ^16.0.5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what kind of element you expect, you can pass a type parameter to `React.isValidElement`.

Replace this:

```
React.isValidElement(child)
```

with this:

```
React.isValidElement<Props>(child)
```